# C#: Reading an XML file (Rekordbox output XML), modifying, saving it back

Tags: c#, xml

First of all, sorry if this is a stupid question - I'm not very educated in C#.

What I want to do is read an XML file - namely, the XML file exported by Rekordbox - and modify it / add some tags.

The XML basically contains a lot of information and a list of tracks, example given:

```
<DJ_PLAYLISTS Version="1.0.0">
  <PRODUCT Name="rekordbox" Version="5.8.0" Company="Pioneer DJ"/>
  <COLLECTION Entries="1">
   <TRACK TrackID="1" Name="We Love XML" Artist="DJ File"
           Composer="" Album="Rekordbox" Grouping="" Genre="Electronic"
           Kind="MP3 File" Size="13908605" TotalTime="345" DiscNumber="0"
           TrackNumber="4" Year="2018" AverageBpm="134.00" DateAdded="2018-05-16"
           BitRate="320" SampleRate="44100" Comments=""
           PlayCount="0" Rating="0" Location="file://localhost/C:/Users/DJFile/Music/DJ File Hits/We Love XML"
           Remixer="" Tonality="B" Label="" Mix="">
      <TEMPO Inizio="0.098" Bpm="134.00" Metro="4/4" Battito="1"/>
      <POSITION_MARK Name="" Type="0" Start="0.098" Num="-1"/>
    </TRACK>
  </COLLECTION>
  <PLAYLISTS>
    <NODE Type="0" Name="ROOT" Count="0"/>
  </PLAYLISTS>
</DJ_PLAYLISTS>
```

The thing is - I am not interested in the exact file format.
All I want to do is parse the tracks list, and modify / add "POSITION_MARK" entries.
So - I want to read the original file, and save it back just as it is/was, just adding one or more "POSITION_MARK" entries.

So my question is - how do I read a random XML file, modify just the TRACK entries I'm interested in, and save it back containing all the original information plus my additions?

Comment: Begin your research into the [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview) class.

Answer (score 1):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement track = doc.Descendants("TRACK").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement newPostitionMark = new XElement("POSITION_MARK", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("Name", "John"),
                new XAttribute("Type", 5),
                new XAttribute("Start", 1.0),
                new XAttribute("Num", 0)
            });
            track.Add(newPostitionMark);

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }
}
```